# How do I get the DAY_OF_YEAR from a Date Picker in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am building a simple app for my job.  What I have so far is a layout that changes every day of the week and lets us know the remedial tasks we have to do for that day.  I recently tried to incorporate a DatePicker in to this.  Which works somewhat as I used the DatePicker tutorial and can pull the Day of Month, Month, and Year no problem.  But what I really want is the DAY_OF_YEAR.  I am having one hell of a time trying to figure this out as I cannot find anything on it.

The reason I need this is that when the user chooses a different day, I want the application to be able to show him the upcoming tasks for that day, as well as the day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

If the math is more problematic than you want, then create a Calendar object and let Java do it for you. Call something like:

```
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
int day = calendar.get(DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about calculating the day of year then?

You have the year, that should tell you how many days the february has. ((YEAR%4==0)?29:28)

You have the month, so you know which months came before

You have the day of month.